# I'm not sure how to mark the clause boundaries

Tags: grammar, linguistics

I'm trying to mark clause boundaries (main, subordinate & embedded clause); I can't play my own devil's advocate anymore, would be so grateful if anyone could weigh in on this:

### Sentence:

> With more than 430,000 migrants having reached Europe by sea this
>   year, the countries of Europe resurrecting borders they'd once
>   removed, and thousands of people in Calais trying to reach Britain
>   illegally, some people have argued that we're on the verge of a 'great
>   age of migration', in which national governments are powerless to
>   resist huge numbers of people, travelling the world in search of a
>   better life.

### Analysis:

- **Clause 1 (objects of the preposition 'with' ?):**

  > With (more than 430,000 migrants having reached Europe by sea this
  >   year), (the countries of Europe resurrecting borders [[(that) they'd
  >   once removed]]), and (thousands of people in Calais trying to reach
  >   Britain illegally), some people have argued...
- **Clause 2 (dependent clause because of verbal process 'argued'):**

  > (everything after 'in which' modifies 'great age') that we're on the
  >   verge of a 'great age of migration', [[in which national governments
  >   are powerless to resist huge numbers of people, [[travelling the world
  >   in search of a better life]].

  *OR*

  Going by the idea that every clause has a verbal group, which means I would split up Clause 1 as well.
- **Clause 3**:

  > in which national governments are powerless
- **Clause 4**:

  > to resist huge numbers of people, [[(who are) travelling the world in search of a better life]].

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site: ) I've tried to make your question easier to scan down, as with the nested brackets, I found it hard to read, but please feel free to revert if I've lost some of your intended meaning.

Comment: This time of year the Claus boundaries are marked by whiskers.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to split it into two sections; the initial large preposition phrase containing several sub clauses and functioning as an omissible adjunct, and the subsequent main clause with its own numerous SCs:

**PP Adjunct**

*With* [*more than 430,000 migrants having reached Europe by sea this year*], [*the countries of Europe resurrecting borders* [*they'd once removed*], *and* [*thousands of people in Calais trying* [*to reach Britain illegally*]].

The PP is headed by the prep *with*, which has as its complement 3 coordinated sub clauses, 2 of which contain further sub clauses:

**1)** *more than 430,000 migrants having reached Europe by sea this year*.

**2)** *the countries of Europe resurrecting borders* [*they’d once removed*], containing the relative clause *they'd once removed* which modifies the NP *borders*.

**3)** *thousands of people in Calais trying* [*to reach Britain illegally*] containing the clause *to reach Britain illegally*, which is catenative complement to *trying*.

**Main Clause**

[*Some people have argued* [*that we're on the verge of a 'great age of migration'* [*in which national governments are powerless* [*to resist huge numbers of people*, [*travelling the world in search of a better life*]]]]].

The MC contains 4 sub clauses:

**1)** the large *that*-content clause as complement to *have argued*, and containing:

**2)** the relative *in which* clause modifying the NP *great age of migration*, which in turn contains:

**3)** the infinitival *to resist* clause as complement to *powerless*, which contains:

**4)** the participial *travelling*  clause modifying the NP *huge numbers of people*.

(note: some grammars would analyse the *having* in *having reached Europe* as a catenative verb with *reached Europe* thus a sub clause as catenative complement. To keep it simple, I've treated *having reached* as a constituent, i.e. 'the verb'.

Comment: @A. Brown Yes, it would.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your replies gave me so much clarity. 

I'm actually trying to do a transitivity analysis (identifying Actor, Process, Goal and circumstance in a ranking clause), so in view of what you said earlier:

MAIN CLAUSE: 

Circumstance - PP Adjunct
Actor - Some people
Process - have argued

DEPENDENT CLAUSE:
(because 'that' functions as a subordinate conjunction, the clause can be deemed as a dependent clause and not an embedded.)

Actor - we
Process (relational) - are
Goal - on the verge of a 'great age of migration'

Comment: @A. Brown The that- content clause is subordinate and embedded within the larger clause.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my effort to show the clause structure using indentation:

- With

  - more than 430,000 migrants having reached Europe by sea this year,
  - the countries of Europe resurrecting borders they'd once removed, and
  - thousands of people in Calais trying to reach Britain illegally,
- some people have argued

  - that we're on the verge of a 'great age of migration',

    - in which national governments are powerless to resist

      - huge numbers of people travelling the world in search of a better life.

Comment: Nicely done, Greg (though I'd call 'trying to reach' and 'powerless to resist' two clauses each). Note that there's a main verb in each clause (_reach, resurrect, try, reach, argue, be on the verge, be powerless, resist, travel_), and often a bunch of auxiliary verbs. That's the giveaway -- every main verb is the nucleus of its own clause, which may get worn down.